# change fontsize depending on resolution bootstrap

Tags: html, css, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to build a website. I was wondering though if there is anyway to change font sizes depending on which resolution the website is displaying. I have some header font that is displaying at 140 px which looks great in desktop mode but when viewing on a phone it becomes a problem. I am fairly new to development so all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Read up on "CSS media queries".

Answer (score 5):

Use simple media queries:

Example:

```
@media all and (min-width: 300px) {
    .font {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/7qYmD/

Reference:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/